# Vue.js - Full circle parent props to child event and back

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I want to do is pass props from parent to child, then update those props by emitting an event back to the parent. When this round trip happens I want the child component to be updated. Right now its not.

[You can see my working code here](https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io)

I verified that the parent is being updated. But for some reason the child component is not being updated and I'm not sure why?

Here is my parent component

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <credential_instructions class="no_background"></credential_instructions>
    <credential_details
      :amazonCredsArray="amazonCredsArray[0]"
      @addComponent="amazonCredsArray[0].push($event)" 
      @removeComponent="amazonCredsArray[0].pop()"
      xs12
      class="no_background"
      >
    </credential_details>
  </v-app>  
</template>

<script>
/*global top*/

import {dataShare} from '../packs/application.js';
import credential_instructions from '../components/credential_instructions.vue';
import credential_details from '../components/credential_details.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

var url = "https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      amazonCredsArray: [],
      components: [],
    };
  },
  components: {
    credential_instructions,
    credential_details
  },
  created() {
    // let self = this;
    dataShare.$on('addComponent', (data) => {
      console.log("how long is the array before? " + this.amazonCredsArray.length )
      if(this.amazonCredsArray.length == 1){
        this.amazonCredsArray.push(data);
      }
      else {
        this.amazonCredsArray[0].push(data);
      }
      console.log("what's the length of the array at the end? " + this.amazonCredsArray.length)
    });
    dataShare.$on('removeComponent', (data) => {
      this.amazonCredsArray[0].pop();
    });
    axios.get(url + "/return_amazon_credentials").then(response => {
      this.amazonCredsArray.push(response.data);
    });
  }
};  

</script>
```

And then this is the child where the event is emitted back to the parent:

```
<v-flex mb-3 class="fullLayoutorHalf(amazonCredsArray)">
   <v-btn fab dark large mb-3 color="green" @click="addCounter()">
      <v-icon dark>add</v-icon>
   </v-btn>
      <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text">Add additional marketplaces</h1>
</v-flex>
```

Finally this is the method that emits the event back to the parent

```
addCounter() {
  this.counter++;
  dataShare.$emit('addComponent', this.counter);
},
```

Where did I go astray?

EDIT:
Oh wow I just found this.. I think this might be the solution. [Caveat for updating a parent array](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Comment: why are you using `amazonCredsArray[0]` the index 0

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim because `amazonCredsArray` is an array of hashes that is created on the server side. And then I have to make the data element `amazonCredsArray` an array on the Vue side. So I end up creating an array within an array. To remove that I use `amazonCredsArray[0]`